# Using FindControl to find a control on another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a site that has Register and Login page that inherited a master page. In this job, I want the application to check if an eMail is already existing in the database when new user attempt to register, if the eMail exist it will redirect to Login page and show a message on a Label on the Login page.

My check code is working.
But my problem is that I can't Find the Label control in the Login page, I need help please.
below is my code in Register page:

the Label ID on Login aspx page is eMailExist

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    Label Exist = (Label)Master.FindControl("eMailExist");
    Exist.Text = "eMail already in use, try Loging in";
}
```

Comment: You should store your condition to Sesson, QueryString... and set the Label in Login page.

Comment: The code after `Response.Redirect` will not get executed, I have posted an answer with a cool suggestion for you to solve this, please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will not workout, since the code after `Response.Redirect` will not execute as it loads the `Login` page, But I have a nice idea for you use some querystring parameters to update the labels in the login page, it will be something like this:

The Redirect will be like this:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?MsgCode=1");
```

And you have to add the following in the page load of the login.aspx.cs

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string messageCode = Request.QueryString["MsgCode"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageCode))
    {
        switch (messageCode)
        {
            case "1" :
                lbleMailExist.Text = "eMail already in use, try Loging in";
                break;
            case "2" :
                lbleMailExist.Text = "Operation time-out, try Loging in";
                break;
                // populate conditions 
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped. hope that you wont forget to mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)